# Java keyListener

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, keyevent

I need some help on my java code I'm a newbie in java, What I want to do is once I press a letter I want to display some message just to verify that the code works. Using javax swing library specifically the keylistener and key event and I don't know if I'm doing it right. 
here are my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
public class KeyStrokeButton{
    public JFrame frame;
    public JPanel panel;
    public JButton btnfocus, btnrelease, btnwindow, btnancestor;
    public JTextField text;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run()
            {
                KeyStrokeButton mydesign = new KeyStrokeButton();
                mydesign.design();
            }
        });
    }

    public void design()
    {


        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);

        frame = new JFrame("Keystroke Tutorials");
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setSize(250, 250);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        btnfocus = new JButton("<html><center>Focus");
        btnfocus.setBounds(10, 10, 90, 80);
        panel.add(btnfocus);
        btnfocus.addKeyListener(new ClickPressed());


        btnrelease = new JButton("Release");
        btnrelease.setBounds(110, 10, 90, 80);
        panel.add(btnrelease);


        btnancestor = new JButton("Ancestor");
        btnancestor.setBounds(10, 100, 90, 80);
        panel.add(btnancestor);


        btnwindow = new JButton("Window");
        btnwindow.setBounds(110, 100, 90, 80);
        panel.add(btnwindow);
    }
    class ClickPressed implements KeyListener
    {
        public void KeyPressed(KeyEvent e)
        {
            //any code.
        }
    }
}
```

as much as possible I want to separate my code for the event, so I create a class to make it readable.

Comment: So are you getting errors? (if not, then you're probably doing it right)

Comment: I don't think you want to use KeyListener for buttons. You might want to consider adding ActionListeners to your buttons via the  addActionListener method.

Answer (score 6):

`KeyListener` in this context is based on the current focus.  That is, key events will only be delivered to the component that current has focus.

So, for example, you have 3 buttons. The focus button will only ever receive a key event when it has focus.  If any other component has focus, the focus button will not receive key events.

Generally speaking, `KeyListener`s are not a good idea.  You're much better using the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

A better explanation of what you are trying to achieve would help us further.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know whether there's a real question lurking anywhere in what you've posted. But judging from your code, here're a couple of pointers:

- Setting a null layout is never a good idea. As a basic step learn about layouts. So read about setting layouts over here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html
- You also need to learn how to work with KeyListeners. Here's another link that might help you with this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html

I hope this will help you get started.

Answer (score 4):

Sujay's answer will give you all the info you need, but here is a quick example of listening for key events.

You can add a global key listener to your JFrame by adding this after launch:

```
KeyboardFocusManager manager = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
manager.addKeyEventDispatcher (new MyDispatcher());
```

You then need to create a key event dispatcher, and add your code into it

```
   private class MyDispatcher implements KeyEventDispatcher
    {
        @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == 38) //up key
            {
            //Do something when the up key is pressed
            System.out.println("The up key was pressed");
            }
            else if (e.getKeyCode() == 40) //down key
            {
                //Do something when the down key is pressed
                System.out.println("The down key was pressed");
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Key bindings are a better alternative to key listeners.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code to build a KeyListener within a JFrame: the code is set up so that the enter and escape keys are detected when pressed.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

class KeyListener extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {               // Required for      KeyListener override

}
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {                  // Required for     KeyListener override

}
}
public KeyListener() {

addKeyListener(this);        // KeyListener added to JFrame to detect key strokes
setFocusable(true);          // Ensure JFrame can gain focus

}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {    // Code to handle when key pressed
int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
switch( keyCode ) { 
case KeyEvent.VK_ENTER:          // Code to handle when enter key pressed

    // ENTER CODE HERE

    break;
case KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE:        // Code to handle when Escape key pressed
    // ENTER CODE HERE
    break;
```

}
}